Where should this to be defined? [Gluon Attach] System Property javafx.platform is not defined
INFO: [Gluon Attach] System Property javafx.platform is not defined
Where should this to be defined?
graalvmjdk21
javafx-21.0.4-javadoc
javafx-jmods-21.0.4
javafx-scenebuilder 22.0.0
javafx-sdk-21.0.4
zulu-21.0.4
Using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.4 (Ultimate Edition) Windows 11.0 Memory: 4056M Cores: 32
Non-Bundled Plugins:  com.intellij.classic.ui (242.20224.159)  com.intellij.javafx (1.0.4)
com.gluonhq.plugin.intellij (2.8.6)  org.jetbrains.android (242.23726.103)
javafx java intellij-idea gluonfx gluon gluon-desktop gluon-mobile

I think you are running using the incorrect maven target, try using:  mvn gluonfx:run
